# How to store hexencoded ciphertext in Java

Tags: java, encryption

I am tasked with finding the secret message and I believe that I will have to XOR the different ciphertexts, but I don't understand how to store a ciphertext in a variable in Java.

I could not find out how to store a ciphertext message. I thought that I would do so by declaring it a string (obviously wrong)

`String firstmessage = "315c4eeaa8b5f8aaf9174145bf43e1784b8fa00dc71d885a804e5ee9fa40b16349c146fb778cdf2d3aff021dfff5b403b510d0d0455468aeb98622b137dae857553ccd8883a7bc37520e06e515d22c954eba5025b8cc57ee59418ce7dc6bc41556bdb36bbca3e8774301fbcaa3b83b220809560987815f65286764703de0f3d524400a19b159610b11ef3e"`

How can I store this value in Java?

Comment: Do you know that String literals are placed between double quotes? besides of that your need to convert you cipher text to some bits, i.e. you need to store it in a byte array `byte[]`.

Comment: How can this be stored as a byte array? By declaring byte[] firstmessage = byte[]. How many elements are in the array? And how would you initialize the elements in the array, using a for loop?

Comment: If your input is a hex string then every character represents 4 bits, a `byte` can hold 8 bits. So for a text of the length `n` you will need a byte array of the length `n/2`, see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/140861/1113392) for how to do the conversion.

Comment: Well, you need a semicolon at the end.  But the above should store the value ... as a String literal.  One would need to know what you intend to do with it after that.

Comment: Writing a simple character hex to byte array converter would be a good educational experience for you.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough, Java still does not pack hexadecimal decoder in one of the main packages handling bytes etc. The best way is to use one of the hexadecimal decoders [from Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html#base16()), the [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/archives/1.9/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#decode(java.lang.Object)) or an internal class within the [Bouncy Castle provider (the "lightweight API")](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/util/encoders/Hex.html#decode(java.lang.String)).

Of course, if you want to you can also use the internal [`DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseHexBinary(java.lang.String)) method, but it is in a rather unrelated XML package in `javax`. Otherwise, you can use additional methods defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/140131/589259).

Comment: Well, he doesn't appear to need a hex ENcoder, and Long.parseLong(String,int) will parse character hex into long values just fine.  One simply needs to build a loop around it.

Comment: @HotLicks "I could not find out how to store a ciphertext message"...to XOR. How the heck do you come to the conclusion that that should be a hex decoder for long values? +simple typo, thanks for the downvote.